# install failing for libpcap: recipe for target pcap-linux.o failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pcap

Just finished installing ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop version. Now I am trying to install libpcap. So far performed the following steps:

1. Downloaded libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz
2. tar -zxvf libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz
3. cd libpcap-1.8.1
4. ./configure && make && sudo make install

I am receiving the following error:

./pcap-linux.c:248:31: fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
Makefile:79 recipe for target 'pcap-linux.o' failed
make: *** [pcap-linux.o] Error 1

What step am I missing?

I do not have internet access on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is missiing the following libraries:

```
libnl-3-dev

libnl-genl-3-dev
```

You can easily find (on a machine with internet connection) the packages where you can find the missing files with the following apt command:

```
apt-file search /netlink/genl/genl.h
```

Comment: Thanks Alessandro.  Unfortunately I only have one linux machine with no internet connection.  Do you know where I can download the file from the internet?

Comment: Here you go man:
https://packages.debian.org/it/wheezy/libnl-genl-3-dev for libnl-genl-3-dev  and https://packages.debian.org/it/wheezy/libnl-3-dev for libnl-3-dev. You just have to choose the arch.

Comment: For Ubuntu you should download the packages from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3 instead (although the Debian packages will probably work fine).

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of downloading *binary* packages then why not simply download the appropriate libpcap0.8 .deb directly? http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpcap0.8/download

Comment: @steeldriver indeed, that would be much simpler!